# How to set Firebase RTDatabse rules to allow only access from cloudfunctions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I'm not understanding the logic behind the RTDB rules. All the examples show how to allow/deny access using user identification ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-behavior)). To me, the only layer of protection I need is to allow access from my Cloudfunctions script, and nothing more.

Is this possibile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are accessing the realtime database using cloud functions only, you can simply remain in locked mode.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

As cloud functions use the admin SDK to access the realtime database, they are not affected by realtime database client access rules.

Comment: Just one more details: this works only if in CF database access is via firebase-admin api